# Asignar un intent a cada item de un spinner

Tags: android-studio, if, spinner

Buenas, tengo un `spinner` con los siguientes valores: Profesor y Alumno, mi pregunta es, como hago para que si la persona escogió **Profesor del spinner** lo dirija a una `activity`, pero si escogió Alumno del `spinner` lo direccione otra `activity`,para que mi pregunta sea mas comprensible les dejo mi código

```
    Spinner tipuus;
    String[] tipos={"Elija una opción","Alumno","Profesor"};
    //---------------------------
    tipuus= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spntipusu);
    //---------------------------
    ArrayAdapter<String> listatipusu=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,tipos);
    tipuus.setAdapter(listatipusu);
    //---------------------------
    btnregistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (tipuus.equals("Alumno")){
                         Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Usted a escogido alumno", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }if (tipuus.equals("Profesor")){
                         Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Usted a escogido profesor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Usted no ha escogido un tipo de usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Ya se que la parte de `tipuus.equals("Alumno")` esta mal, me gustaría saber como seria el código para que haga lo que pido. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el item selecionado dentro de tu `spinner` usas:

```
tipuus.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("alumno") // dentro del "" debe ir un String que exista en tu arreglo. es este caso alumno o profesor.
```

Luego debes añadir un intent dentro de un condición `if`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(nombre_actividad_actual.this,nombre_actividad_destino.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                nombre_activdad_actual.this.finish();
```

Quedaria asi :

```
 btnregistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (tipuus.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("alumno"))){
                             Intent intent = new Intent(nombre_actividad_actual.this,alumno.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                nombre_activdad_actual.this.finish();

                    } else if (tipuus.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("profesor")){
Intent intent = new Intent(nombre_actividad_actual.this,´profesor.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                nombre_activdad_actual.this.finish();

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Usted no ha escogido un tipo de usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Como nota, debes diferenciar el uso del `if` y el `else if`. el **if** evalúa todas las condiciones y el **else if** al encontrar una que sea **true** se detiene y ejecuta la acción que se encuentra dentro de el. Ayuda a optimizar tu app.